# Does the order of command line flags matter?

Tags: bash, zsh

I am testing Hugo static blog generator which comes with themes and example sites within them.

In order to easily use exampleSite, I just copy the content it's content to Hugo project root. While I did this, I noticed that where, I put the -flag args seems to be important.

Is this is a normal bash behavior or something introduced by zsh?

This command didn't work

```
cp themes/hugo-theme-bootstrap4-blog/exampleSite/* . -R
```

This command worked!

```
cp -R themes/hugo-theme-bootstrap4-blog/exampleSite/* .
```

Comment: I believe this is completely dependent on the executable being run, not on the shell.  Some programs treat "everything at the end" (a.k.a. "positional arguments") differently than the rest of the arguments and flags.

Comment: What 0x5453 said. The options are interpreted by the command, and `cp` is not a part of bash, it's simply a program that can be run by it. `man cp` to see usage instructions for your operating system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cp` is its own command, provided by your OS vendor. Neither bash nor zsh controls the behavior of `cp`.

The POSIX standard only requires `cp` to accept options **before** arguments. This is given in [POSIX utility syntax guidelines](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html), entry #9:

> 9. All options should precede operands on the command line.

GNU tools go beyond this requirement, accepting options after arguments unless `--` is given prior (as described in guideline #10).

Comment: The *openpubs.org* [**Detailed ToC**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/contents.html) could sure use being brought into the 21st century... Glad you dropped the link.